Compressing clipped rasters (batch process) in QGIS
I am brand new to QGIS. I need to clip and compress 30 drone rasters. I do not know how to enter the command into the batch process window to compress the images. Right now, the only settings I have changed are selecting 'no' for 'Matching the extent of the clipped raster to the extent of the mask layer', 'yes' for 'keep resolution of input rater', and 'yes' for 'use multithreaded warping implementation'. This took my rasters from 30+ KB to 97KB. The original raster size is about 40 KB.
